# Typo3 4.5, PiBase Extension, Ajax Call with eID, how to access configuration?

Tags: php, typo3

So i have been assigned a task that would normally be trivial, but it has to work on a rather old Typo3-Website (4.5). I am very unexperienced with Typo3.
To make an AJAX call, i found out that i need an eID, my own class file, i found out how to call the main function and all that.
Now, i have a lot of configuration in many different locations, and i need to access that information.
In the `class.tx_as_es_pi1.php` the `function main($content, $conf)` has this very handy parameter `$conf`. It seems this is made available by some Typo3 magic. Trying to somehow mimick this behaviour, i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835380/typo3-eid-how-to-access-config) answer, and it provides me with some of the configuration, using these lines:

```
$conf = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_ases_pi1.'];
var_dump($conf);
```

I get this result:

```
 'includeLibs' => string 'typo3conf/ext/as_es/pi1/class.tx_as_es_pi1.php' (length=46)
  'userFunc' => string 'tx_ases_pi1->main' (length=17)
```

but the Typoscript Object Browser shows a lot more (including what i need):

```
[tx_ases_pi1] = USER_INT # TypoScript added by extension "as_es" # Setting as_es plugin TypoScript
    [includeLibs] = typo3conf/ext/as_es/pi1/class.tx_as_es_pi1.php
    [userFunc] = tx_ases_pi1->main
    [config_template] = EXT:as_es/templates/results_elkwue.htm 
    [config_template_extended] = EXT:as_es/templates/extended_elkwue.htm
    [config_searchaccesskey] = someAccessKey
    [config_searchproxy] = someProxyUrl
    [config_searchfilterurl] = soeSearchFilterUrl
    [config_searchshowstat] = 1
    [config_utf8decode] = 1
    [config_maxtitlelength] = 50
    [config_removefromtitle] = SomeString
    [config_piwiktracking_host] = somePiwikHost
    [config_piwiktracking_port] = 80
    [config_piwiktracking_id] = SomeID
[config_fedebug_messages_search] = {$plugin.tx_ases_pi1.configuration.fedebug_messages_search}
```

So, obvously, there is something i do not really understand here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

[EDIT] The answer in the related question only provides some of the configuration data, as shown above. I am looking for a hint on how to retrieve the rest of the data.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. If anything, it is a request for clarification. As my question states, i tried the solution in that question, but it did not help me.

Comment: You are right, this is not a duplicate - sorry for the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found the answer to this, in [this](http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/getting-GLOBALS-TSFE-gt-tmpl-gt-setup-plugin-myext-in-eID-td113838.html) old post.
In the eID - class, add this method:

```
/**
  * Initializes TSFE and sets $GLOBALS['TSFE'].
  *
  * @return void
  */
protected function initTSFE() {
    $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_fe',
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], t3lib_div::_GP('id'), '');
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToDB();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->checkAlternativeIdMethods();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->determineId();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getCompressedTCarray();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();

    // Get linkVars, absRefPrefix, etc
    TSpagegen::pagegenInit();
}
```

and in the `main()` method, call it: `$this->initTSFE();` . Then this call:

```
$conf = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_ases_pi1.'];
var_dump($conf);
```

will output the complete list.

I am not claiming i would really understand it... but since it might save others some trouble, i am posting it anyway.

[EDIT]
Apparently it was this line:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->checkAlternativeIdMethods();
```

that made the difference. Removing it would result in the short output shown in the question.
As a side note: these lines:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getCompressedTCarray();
TSpagegen::pagegenInit();
```

do not make a difference for me, so i assume that they can be omitted in my case to speed things up a little.
I will leave them in here because they might help someone else in the future.